# Who was the other person the colossal titan ate?

Tags: attack-on-titan

At the beginning of episode 7 of season 2 (episode 32 on Crunchyroll), around 1:48, the colossal titan eats Ymir and one other person.

[image: Two people being eaten by a titan]
<sup>You can't see their face in any part of the episode.</sup>

Given who the colossal titan is, it seems strange to me that he would have eaten someone without a purpose, but only Ymir is seen later.

Eventually, they run off on the armoured titans back and the second person is not with them.

Surely they could not have been digested in the short time the colossal titan was present, and they were swallowed whole.

Later on, when we see them in human form in the giant forest, no one besides Eren and Ymir are with them. Do we know who this person was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was an unnamed, unlucky poor individual who was at the wrong place at the wrong time. If you watch [this Youtube](https://youtu.be/go3KVXM-fgg?t=19) video, they aren't entirely sure who the Colossal Titan ate either.

> It got Ymir!
>
> ...
>
> And they got somebody else, too!

Also, while reading [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/attackontitan/comments/6gwxm6/does_anyone_know_who_the_second_person_the/) post, people say the Colossal Titan ate him to steal his ODM Gear

> Just a random person. They didn't care about the guy, only about stealing his gear.

This is confirmed by seeing the Colossal Titan wearing the ODM gear in it's human form in the [scene](https://youtu.be/kZGBY8v-GGU?t=29) when they were camping out in the forest

Comment: Did not think about the gear, that makes sense since the armored titan took Eren's gear, the colossal titan needed gear too.

Answer (score 3):

The other soldier that Bertoldt ate along with Ymir was killed and used by Bertholdt for the soldier's 3DMG to help Reiner and Bertoldt escape with Eren and Ymir in tow.

Here is Armin explaining it to Mikasa in chapter 45 of the manga:
[Attack on Titan chapter 45 page 24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSUHk.jpg)

(Note: While I have seen the Attack on Titan anime, I prefer the manga version of the series so my answer is based on the manga version of the events as opposed to the anime. But it doesn't really make a difference here because season 2 of the series did a a fantastic job of keeping most things exactly like they happened in the manga.)!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose since Ymir is

> the jaw titan

he wouldn't eat her, which is why she is seen later. Supposedly he put them in his mouth for safe-keeping. Maybe that other soldier was grabbed by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other person that the Colossal Titan ate was (**spoiler alert** for season 2's ending)

> the Beast Titan, because at the end, a blond-haired shirtless man wearing glasses emerged from the Beast Titan's nape. Also, that would explain his random disappearance because on episode 4 in season 2, he climbed the wall and was never shown again till the ending.